# Power shell script to split all excel file in a folder based on a column begins with F or S a save as Tab delimiter

Tags: excel, powershell

i have mutiple excel files in a folder, consider i have 2 columns.

```
ColA- City 
Colb-name
```

what i want is to read all excel file  one by one and split the data using `ColA` begins with F and save the filtered value in a separate folder as tab delimiter

in `ColA` i will have F or S i need F and S data to be saved. what is the easiest way to do this.

Comment: What did you try so far? Did you read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: what i did is as below , i am new to powershell and were able to perform for 1 file, but i need to do it for multiple files in a folder

Comment: i have attached the code below

Comment: Include your attempt in the original question.